# Setting persistent cookies with javascript

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have found a weird bug in my application and due to my small experience with Javascript I couldn't debug it;

I am trying to set a persistent cookie, which will die after one year from its set (max value in major browsers) but persists and won't be deleted after the browser gets closed. I've been using this code:

```
// Build the expiration date string:
var expiration_date = new Date();
expiration_date.setYear (expiration_date.getYear () + 1);
expiration_date = expiration_date.toGMTString();
// Build the set-cookie string:
var cookie_string = "test_cookies = true; path=/; expires=" + expiration_date;
// Create/update the cookie:
document.cookie = cookie_string;
```

I've noticed that the cookie has a session tag when I use cookie manager plugin, and only the ones with this tag get removed when the browser shuts down (others like Wordpress's and such scripts persist).

Comment: Expiry dates PREVENT it from being deleted when the browser is closed. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I changed your syntax over to my style of coding (variables at the top, minimal re-casting, etc.) and the example below works on my localhost quite well.

```
// Build the expiration date string:
var expiration_date = new Date();
var cookie_string = '';
expiration_date.setFullYear(expiration_date.getFullYear() + 1);
// Build the set-cookie string:
cookie_string = "test_cookies=true; path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toUTCString();
// Create or update the cookie:
document.cookie = cookie_string;
```

If you are having problems on a production server, try setting the domain of the cookie as well ([www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#link5](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html#link5))

Comment: Hi @pete, do you know how can we add this persist in js-cookie script? Thx!

Comment: @Gregdebrick I'm not sure *which* `js-cookie` script you're referring to, so off-hand, no. In any case, your comment has the makings of a great question! You should ask it as a separate question. :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076394/how-can-we-add-a-persistent-cookie-to-js-cookie ;)

Comment: Well, this stopped working recently. In Firefox's storage inspector I can manually set the "Expires / Max-Age" column to the date generated by the method you used and it works. But setting the "expires=" part to the date string in the code (no matter if with or without surrounding quotes) sets the above-mentioned column always to "Session".

Comment: I now realized my function to change the expiry date can still change it successfully, so I now rewrote the function to set the cookie without any expiry date and then change the expiry date to the desired date. That works both in all Firefox profiles I have and in UngoogledChromium.

Answer (score 6):

You can also use the `max-age` attribute.

```
cookie_string = "test_cookies=true; path=/; max-age=31536000";
```

- One week: max-age=604800
- One month: max-age=2628000
- One year: max-age=31536000

Answer (score 2):

have you tried using the `getFullYear()` and `setFullYear()` methods of the `Date` instance instead of `getYear()` and `setYear()` ? the latter are are deprecated, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date#Methods_2).

hope that helps! cheers.