# sessionStorage - only do a behavior on initial page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, session

I don't understand how sessionStorage works. I want to have an event happen on only the initial page load.

I'm (trying) to do this by checking if the session is new. The idea is below:

```
$(function() {
  sessionStorage.setItem('isNewSession', 'true');
  if (sessionStorage.getItem("isNewSession")) {
    // do stuff on the first page load
  } else {
    // don't do it after
  }
});
```

So when the page first loads, it looks like the `sessionStorage` is set to `true`. After that, during the duration of the users visit to the page, what I want to happen only once always happens, because I can see `sessionStorage` is always `true`.

If I set it to `false` if sessionStorage returns `true` then obviously what I want to happen just won't happen.

I investigated a [session cookie](https://www.webopedia.com/TERM/S/session_cookie.html) but this again persists throughout the users visit, and not just the first load.

How do I handle this? How can I have an event fire *only on initial page load, and **not** throughout the remaining users visit?*

FOR CONTEXT: The "event" is an animation in the navigation bar.

Comment: When animation ends then sessionStorage.setItem('isNewSession', 'false'); ?  maybe I don't understand the problem.

Comment: @Emeeus no because then it get sets to false, and the animation just doesn't run...

Comment: "I want to have an event happen on only the initial page load" I assume just once each user, right? because if not it's not necessary to use sessionStorage , because $(whatever).ready() accomplish the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly `sessionStorage` is not appropriate for this kind of task, since it will be lost once the users closes the tab. You should use `localStorage` for this.

[From mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage object for the current origin. sessionStorage is similar to Window.localStorage; the only difference is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, **data stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends**. A page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives over page reloads and restores.

And secondly you set *isNewSession* before checking it. While you should only set it, if you know it's not set.

So your corrected code should look like this:

```
$(function() {
    // Determine if is the first time on this page
    if ( ! localStorage.getItem("beenHereBefore")) {
        localStorage.setItem('beenHereBefore', 'true');
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tcyoswd3/)

Answer (score 0):

Using JavaScript cookies will do the trick:

Below is a slightly modified version of https://stackoverflow.com/a/8733385/2969615, which has been adapted for your purposes:

```
if(getCookie("hasPageBeenOpened")) {
    console.log("welcome back");
} else {
    console.log("first time eh?");

    // Build the expiration date string:
    var expiration_date = new Date();
    expiration_date.setFullYear(expiration_date.getFullYear() + 1);
    // Build the set-cookie string:
    var cookie_string = "hasPageBeenOpened=true; path=/; expires=" + expiration_date.toUTCString();
    // Create or update the cookie:
    document.cookie = cookie_string;
}
```

And the script which reads the cookie, which I grabbed from https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```
function getCookie(cname) {
    var name = cname + "=";
    var decodedCookie = decodeURIComponent(document.cookie);
    var ca = decodedCookie.split(';');
    for(var i = 0; i <ca.length; i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
            c = c.substring(1);
        }
        if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
            return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```