# How can we add a persistent cookie to js-cookie?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, cookies, ruby-on-rails-5

**Context :** I have set a cookie into my Rails app, to display to users only one time a popup (bootstrap modal).

**Goal :** I want to set the cookie for 1 month, with no

**Issue :** the code bellow works fine **but when you close the navigator, the cookie is restarted**. I think is the difference between session vs persistent cookie.

The stack of the app :

- Ruby on Rails
- JS cookie plugin : https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie

**The code :**

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
     if (Cookies('pop') == null) {
         $('#MyModal').modal('show');
         Cookies('pop', '31');
     }
 });
```

**JS-cookie code here :** https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/blob/latest/src/js.cookie.js

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie#cookie-attributes), this should work:

```
Cookies.set('pop', 'any truthy value', { expires: 31 });
```

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (Cookies('pop') == null) {
        $('#MyModal').modal('show');
        Cookies('pop', '31', { expires: 31 });
        // or:
        // Cookies('pop', 'shown', { expires: 31 });
        // Cookies('pop', true, { expires: 31 });
        // Cookies('pop', 'etc.', { expires: 31 });
    }
});
```